# Cronjob is not working as expected (php file)

Tags: php, cron

I have written a script for my customer which downloads youtube videos and uploads them to dailymotion.
When I run dailyuploader.php with browser it works Ok.

Also when I run it from terminal;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
dosya:/www/gokhan/uploads/27-nefes-fuibron-yar-dedim-sana-dj-karaduman-2013.mp4
Directory:/www/gokhan/uploads/27-nefes-fuibron-yar-dedim-sana-dj-karaduman-2013.mp4
Array
(
    [id] => x1tjwo8
    [title] => 27 Nefes & Fuibron - Yar Dedim Sana (Dj Karaduman 2013)
    [channel] => music
    [owner] => x1e8kjt
)
Basarili
```

It works Ok.

But when i add it to crontab It doesn't work as expected.

I get output;

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.28
Content-type: text/html

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
dosya:
Directory:
Dosya yok ya da 0kb
```

My cron command is like this: 
    */20 * * * * /usr/bin/php-cgi /www/gokhan/dailyuploader.php >> /www/gokhan/out.txt

Also I use commands that needs high permissions: rename, (exec with youtube-dl: an application that downloads youtube videos) etc.

Also I have even tried to make chmod 777 all files and directories. 
Also I have changed owner of files to root but result was same.

Any help appreciated.

Edit.1
function that downloads video.

```
function download_video($videoid){
    exec('youtube-dl '. $videoid .' -o "/www/gokhan/uploads/%(title)s.mp4"');
    return true;
}
```

function that gets video path and title to upload.

```
function get_file(){
$dir = opendir("/www/gokhan/uploads/");
while (($dosya = readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
    if(! is_dir($dosya)){
        $title = substr($dosya,0,-4);
        $direc = "/www/gokhan/uploads/";
        $t = seola(substr($dosya,0,-3)).".mp4";
        rename($direc.$dosya, $direc.$t);
        $tabi = $direc.$t;
    }
}
closedir($dir);
echo "dosya:".$tabi."\n";
$ar['dosya'] = $tabi;
$ar['title'] = $title;
return $ar;
}
```

function that uploads file to dailymotion

```
function upload_to_dailymotion($username,$password,$dir,$title){
include('/www/gokhan/Dailymotion.php');
require_once '/www/gokhan/Dailymotion.php';
echo "Directory:".$dir."\n";
$apiKey = "apikey";
$apiSecret = "apisecret";
$api = new Dailymotion();
$api->setGrantType(Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, $apiKey, $apiSecret, array('write','delete'),
array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
if(file_exists($dir) and filesize($dir) > 0){
    $url = $api->uploadFile($dir);
    $result1 = $api->post('/me/videos', array('url' => $url, 'title' => $title , 'description' => '' , 'channel' => 'music', 'tags' => '', 'published' => true));
    print_r($result1);
    $url = $result1['id'];
    return $url;
}
else
    die("Dosya yok ya da 0kb");
}
```

Edit.2 
Function that connects all methods obove..

```
function download_get_link($videoid,$username,$password){
$indirme = download_video($videoid);
$ar= get_file();
$title = $ar['title'];
$dir = $ar['dosya'];
if($indirme){
    $url = upload_to_dailymotion($username,$password,$dir,$title);
    $res['url'] = $url;
    $res['title'] = $title;
    $res['description'] = '';
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: How about posting the relevant parts of your php script?

Comment: @kelunik : I have added relevant parts of the script.

Comment: if you run from crontab you are running without directories. Hardcode them (or use __FILE__) to grab read directory names and then add relative paths.

Comment: Where does `upload_to_dailymotion` get called? What's the content of the parameters which are passed?

Comment: @kelunik I have added that method too. $dir = is files location; /path/to/file/xxx.mp4 $title is title of video which is string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running scripts via a web browser results in all paths being relative to the scripts location. When running them from command line they're relative to your current working directory.

So when you run your script like this:

```
/var$ php www/dir/script.php
```

it won't work either.

You use absolute paths in most parts of your script, but not in your `get_file` function:

```
if(!is_dir($dosya)) {
```

That should be:

```
$direc = "/www/gokhan/uploads/";

while (($dosya = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    if(!is_dir($direc.$dosya)){
        $title = substr($dosya, 0, -4);
        $t = seola(substr($dosya, 0, -3)).".mp4";
        rename($direc.$dosya, $direc.$t);
        $tabi = $direc.$t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The problem was about paths. Changing exec('youtube-dl ...') to exec('/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl ...') was needed too. I didn't tought it was necessary was i was wrong.